# Zend_Form: Add Link before submit-element

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I want to have the link inside the DIV instead before.
I want to have it look like:

```
<div class="clear">
  <a href="somelink">A link</a>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
```

But at the moment it looks like that:

```
<a href="somelink">A link</a>
<div class="clear">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
```

PHP:

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
$submit->setLabel('submit')
       ->setDisableLoadDefaultDecorators(true)
       ->setDecorators(array(
           'ViewHelper',
           array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'clear')),
           array('Description', array('escape' => false, 'tag' => false, 'placement' => 'prepend'))
       ))
       ->setDescription('<a href="somelink">A link</a>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is write your own, custom decorator. [AnyMarkup decorator](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/62/anymarkup-decorator) may be helpful.

You may be interested in this [article about decorators](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3450). There is also nice Matthew's screencast about decorators on Zend Framework page.